# Spring Data dynamic query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, dynamicquery

I'm trying to set up a dynamic query using spring data, basically I have an array with a bunch of characteristics and I need to assemble the query based on those characteristics, pretty much something like "WHERE characteristic = A AND characteristic = B AND  characteristic = C" but the amount of characteristics may vary.

I noticed that I can use the @Query annotation but is it possible to make the result of the @Query pageable ?

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
Page<Recipe> findDistinctByNameContainingAndOrganizationAndCharacteristicsInOrIngredientsContainingAndOrganizationAndCharacteristicsInOrDescriptionContainingAndOrganizationAndCharacteristicsInAllIgnoreCase(
        String name, Organization organization1, List<Characteristic> characteristic1,
        String ingredients, Organization organization2, List<Characteristic> characteristic2,
        String description, Organization organization3, List<Characteristic> characteristic3,
        Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Yes @Query supports Pageable

Comment: Try use QueryDSL. For example in this case you can send any predicate for you repository or service. http://www.querydsl.com/

Comment: For method declarations like these I'd definitely look into other options like `@Query` and Querydsl. This method is effectively unusable due to its long name and parameter list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. `@Query` supports pageable.. and yes there's another way to accomplish this.

You could take a look at building query with criteria, that allow you add AND / OR where conditions dynamically. I actually use querydsl to facilitate my development.

In this post you can find a good explanation of both: http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Altough it could be seem more complex at beginning, the use of this feature will make your code more consistent with increasing complexity

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Data JPA Querydsl. [Read it here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)