# Alternatives to finder methods for every property in Spring JpaRepository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, repository-pattern

I use Spring Data JPA for my repository layer. I need to query entities by every possible property and combinations of its properties. So my typical repository looks like this.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByLogin(String login);
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User findByName(String name);
    User findByLoginAndEmail(String login, String email);
    User findByLoginAndName(String login, String name);
    User findByLoginAndEmailAndName(String login, String email, String name);
    //and so on
}
```

Even with three properties it looks ugly enough.
Are there any more flexible alternatives to this approach? Or this design is OK(at least I do not have to implements all of these methods)?

Comment: You can try something from here https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data dynamic query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017419/spring-data-dynamic-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [query by example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example). Seems it is what I was looking for.